# undefined hidden symbol `__dso_handle' error while building a shared library

Tags: c++, ld

I am trying to build a shared library (on linux) of one of the components of my application.

I am using the following command to create it:

```
g++ -g -shared -Wl,--cref,-Map,ComponentA.map -o ComponentA.so \
 ../../components/componentA_all.o -nostdlib -lgcc
```

At the linking stage I am getting the following errors:

```
/home/manik/components/componentA.cpp:218: undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../components/componentA_all.o: relocation R_386_GOTOFF against undefined hidden symbol `__dso_handle' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:188: recipe for target 'ComponentA.so' failed
```

If I have static arrays of classes in "componentA.cpp", like:

```
static component_info_a cx_objs[10];
```

The line number for the source of error is at this location.
I don't understand what is the cause of the error. The declaration for struct component_info_a is written in the same componentA.cpp file.

The compile command before link stage for this source file is:

```
g++ -Wp,-MMD,componentA.d -pthread -pipe -c -Woverloaded-virtual  -DUSING_X11 -g -D_REENTRANT -pthread -fpic  -I../.. -I/usr/share -frandom-seed=componentA.cpp -fno-stack-protector -Wall   -fno-inline -o componentA.o componentA.cpp
```

There are other source files for the recipe "componentA_all.o", which are:

```
componentA.cpp
componentA_drag.cpp
componentA_multitouch.cpp
```

The command that is used by makefiles to create "componentA_all.o" is:

```
ld -r -o componentA_all.o componentA_drag.o componentA_multitouch.o
```

Comment: you need to check if you linking everything you need.

Comment: if the "componentA_all.o" was successfully created, then it should suffice to say that the linking happened successfully, right ?

Comment: Why are you using `ld` directly? It can't handle C++ files without additional input, and `g++` is supposed to be frontened to the linking tool.

Comment: Assuming `component_info_a` requires a constructor call to initialize it the option `-nostdlib` is going to cause your failure.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious removing "-nostdlib" from the command fixes it. Thank You.